# Morphisms from spectra to schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme. Show that for any $x \in X$ there exists a canonical morphism $\textrm{Spec}\, \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \rightarrow X$. If $k(x)=\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\frak{m}_{x}$ is the residue field at $x$, conclude that there is a canonical morphism $\textrm{Spec}\, k(x) \rightarrow X$.

I came across this exercise while reading through one of my AG texts. I'm a little stuck on how to begin here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean a canonical morphism $\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})\to X$? Same for the residue field?

Comment: Hint:  First do the case $X=Spec(R)$.

Comment: "Isomorphism" is clearly a typo. Take any $X$ which is not a point, then there cannot be an isomorphism $Spec k(x)\to X$.

Comment: @Matt Or take any non-affine scheme, and it doesn't work for either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, the canonical **homomorphism** is almost never an isomorphism. Just see what Matt said; if $X$ is not a point, then they're not even isomorphic as topological spaces.

Hints:

- Since $x$ is a point, it is contained in some affine piece of $X$, say $Spec (A)$.
- $x$ corresponds to some prime ideal $\mathfrak p_x$ of $A$, and the local ring $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ corresponds to the localization $A_{\mathfrak{p}_x}$ (invert everything not in $\mathfrak p_x$). We have a canonical *localization homomorphism* $A \to A_{\mathfrak p_x}$.

Can you see the rest?